# Can we user SwipeRefreshLayout with actionbar sherlock project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat, swiperefreshlayout

I have created a project which uses `ActionBarSherlock` for implementing android `actionbar`.
Now I have to implement swipe refresh for my all `listview`s used in the project.

I need to implement a swipe style, which is similar to the gmail app. For this I add the `app-compact` library project to my application project but showing some errors since i have already added my `ActionbarSherlock` source code as a library project.

How can I find a solution for this Issue?? Guys advance thanx for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) works with any actionbar. you dont have to import app-compact.

Comment: Even I didn't get the suggestion on eclipse too.

Comment: use the latest support v4 lib thats all SwipeRefreshLayout needs